# Magento 2 Running Ridiculously Slow - Best Fix?

Tags: pagespeed, slowbackend, slow-response

I need advice on the best way to approach this. The site is loading pages in 30 seconds, sometimes 1 minute. This will kill my traffic if it's rolled live.

Hosting said:

> I ran an strace on one of the pages, which took 23 seconds to load
>   completely, and ran an strace on it, which records every single system
>   call made by the site during this loading time. There were no specific
>   system calls taking more than than a few milliseconds excluding a call
>   to the main Magento core bootstrap.php which is normal, and that in
>   itself took 1.6 seconds from the total. The rest of the calls as
>   mentioned take milliseconds each, but due to the amount of calls,
>   188979, the process just takes too long.

We have tried changing PHP version - it didn't work.

> I tried several minor fixes like using a different PHP version, temporarily disabling opcache as there were a fair number of calls to files generated by it, but nothing much changes.

URL:
[Staging site - temp URL](http://marieb3.sg-host.com/)

Answer (score 0):

On checking your site,

> 1. **Gzip compression** is not enabled, if enabled it can reduce your page size to nearly 4 MB from 7 MB
> 2. **CSS** and **Javascript** is not minified, it can save up to 1 MB.
> 3. **HTML Minification** is not done.

You can follow the below practices to speed up the site.

> 1. Switch your website to production mode
> 2. Minify your HTML, CSS and js files.
> 3. Merge your CSS and JS files.
> 4. Optimize your images.
> 5. Enable Gzip Compression.
> 6. Ensure if Magento Full Page Cache is enabled. Can install and
>      configure varnish to speed up the site
> 7. Do Advanced Javascript Bundling following this link
>      https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html
>      as it will reduce total page size as well keeping the number of
>      requests low
> 8. Use the profiler to check files consuming more time. Check and ensure
>      to load them in lesser time.
>
> php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html
>
> php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable csvfile
>
> 9. Consider Using Google Page Speed Module in your server where you can
>      configure the optimization to speed up the page as well as increasing
>      your google page speed score significantly. To see if this can solve
>      all your problems
>      https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/
>
> 10.Enable Flat Categories and Products

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I will give these instructions to my developer. I've done the easy ones myself via the Magento backend.